# How to get current line number during "raku -n" iteration?

Tags: raku

In Perl I could:

```
cat file.txt | perl -nE 'say $.'
```

The closest Raku solution i found (without using state counter variable) returns position in bytes:

```
cat file.txt | raku -ne 'say $*IN.tell'
```

Comment: See @Jonathan Worthington's answer.  In an earlier version of Raku, there was a method on each handle that you could call.  But it was deemed too much overhead for the majority of cases where you do *not* need it, so it was removed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a state variable for it and increment that. Most conveniently, there is the anonymous state variable `$`, meaning one can do:

```
echo -e "foo\nbar\nbaz" | perl6 -ne 'say $++ ~ ": $_"'
```

Which gives:

```
0: foo
1: bar
2: baz
```

Use `++$` instead for base-1 numbering. There isn't anything special built in to the handle; it falls neatly out of state variables or, for an explicit iteration, `.lines.kv`, and then it's only paid for by things that want it.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear that there is no `$.`equivalent. State variables for the rescue :)

Comment: Using @Jonathan_Worthington 's suggestion, I can get `raku -e 'lines.keys.say;'` to work just fine (returning all numbers on one line), however mistakenly using the `-ne` flag skips the first input line--resulting in an off-by-one error.

Answer (score 3):

The [LN module](https://github.com/raku-community-modules/perl6-LN) is probably what you want to use.